# Does Wolverine fight for the U.S or for Canada in the WWI montage of X-Men Origins: Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

Wolverine [is supposed to be Canadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)#Fictional_character_biography),  but in the WWI sequence of the opening credits/war montage of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine (2009)*, it [looks like](https://youtu.be/1o9c1w8G94g?t=39s) he is wearing standard U.S military uniform (WWI), but it might be Canadian (I'm no WWI uniform expert).

[image]
[image]

The following WWII D-day sequence suggests that they're fighting for U.S army, specifically [29th Infantry Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/29th_Infantry_Division_(United_States)), which I noticed by the patch on Logan's brother's uniform.

[image]
[image]

But **I'm specifically wondering about the WWI sequence**, and I don't want to *assume* that just because he was a U.S soldier in WWII that he was also one for WWI.

Comment: Basically a dupe http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46290/from-x-men-we-know-that-wolverine-was-canadian-but-in-one-movie-why-did-he-part

Comment: @cde Wrong. I had already read that question, and googled extensively. That question you linked does not answer the question of whether Logan was fighting for the U.S or for the Canadians in that WWI segment.

Comment: @cde You even specifically commented on that question with this: *Not sure if they actually moved to the US, or were US soldiers in WW1/2, or even in Vietnam. The lack of any defining uniform or banner or anything in the war montage makes it hard to tell* ...

Comment: I said basically. Not actually. Hence no close vote.

Comment: @cde Okay, well, that question is asking about the details of the first segment of the montage, the *Civil War*, and the asker was after a disambiguation of what war it was (he believed it was the revolution) and why they were on the U.S side (it's obvious they're American soldiers for that segment). **My question** is not only about a completely different segment, but also asking *which side* they're fighting on, not *why they're fighting for the U.S*

Answer (score 8):

It's not very clear from the movie -- those uniforms could also be Canadian WWI army uniforms -- but I think it's most likely he's fighting for the US. The evidence is very circumstantial, but Logan also fought in the US Civil War. This means that he fought in the Civil War, WW II, and Vietnam war for the US Army, so the *simplest* explanation is that he simply relocated permanently to the US and fought for them. He only moved back to Canada after he abandons Task Force X, in the 1970's.

---

For completeness, I should point out that in the comic source (*Wolverine: Origins*), Logan definitely fought for *Canada* in World War I.

However, his comic book past has been retconned about a dozen times -- in-universe, most of what he thinks is his past is memory implants. There have two *Origins* mini-series and a full *Wolverine: Origins* series just convering Wolverine's back story. He also moves around *a lot* in the comics: he was in Canada in 1907, part of the Canadian army in 1912, he was in Mexico in 1920, Madripoor (fictional, but close to Singapore) in 1932, etc. I'm not sure it's even possible for all of those stories to be simultaneously correct.

So, it's probably not productive to look to the comics material for any specific details about the movie universe.

Comment: This is a nice answer, I voted it up, however, and it pains me to say it, I am specifically looking for an answer that *doesn't* rely on the, as you yourself described it, circumstantial evidence of him fighting for the U.S in the preceding and following war sequences. This question spawned from a heated debate about the glimpses we get of their uniform, weapons etc. I lack the enthusiast knowledge of WWI gear to say for sure either way, but I'd love for someone to provide that extra insight. Nothing against you, or your answer, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

There was no such thing, specifically, as a "Canadian uniform" for WWI. Canada was still considered part of the the British empire during WWI.  They were granted autonomy over most of their affairs in 1932, and complete, separate independence and the ability to amend their own Constitution in 1982.  Canadians fighting in WWI did so as British troops.

[Reference.com: When did Canada gain independence from Great Britain?](https://www.reference.com/history/did-canada-gain-independence-great-britain-417086db06d9389)

> Troops from Canada played a prominent part in World War One. Canada was part of the British Empire in 1914. As a result of this, when Great Britain declared war on Germany in August 1914, Canada was automatically at war.

[History Learning Site: Canada's Role In WWI](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/world-war-one/canada-and-world-war-one/)

So, if that's a bit too picky, and just makes the question "Did they fight for the British or US? -  Doing a quick Google search on US, Canadian British units and British WWI uniforms, they don't seem all that different, FWIW, so I can't tell from memory. 
 I'll try to look closer at screen caps later and see if there's anything distinctive, or if the uniforms are time-period but generic.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Wondering what you found since posting it? One problem I can think of, though, is that we'd have to assume the movie studio was being historically accurate when assigning costumes. It may be that the costumes are ambiguous and indistinct, deliberately.

Answer (score -4):

I would think that they would fight for canada during ww1 and 2 as they wanted to fight in war and the US didnt join the either war at the beginning, they took 3 years to get into each of them, while canada entered the wars at the onset. When war broke out the two would have joined the canadian military and go to war asap

Comment: As explained in the question, Wolverine fights for the US army in the WW2 sequence ... so your premise is incorrect. Also, your premise is based on nothing except "I think", so, if I could vote down twice I would.